# UFT : How to identify a webEdit in a dynamic webtable

Tags: hp-uft

I have a dynamic webtable on a page in which i have to set values one by one. There is button to add webedit to that table.When i click on that button a webedit is get added, then i have to set a value in that. Same process i have to repeat for different values.

All the webedits have same properties only the **name is different like**

`"name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l1\$ABCName" "name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l2\$ABCName" 
 "name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l3\$ABCName" . . . 
 "name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l200\$ABCName"`

I am not able to identify the newly added webedit.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a consistency in the `name` property you can identify the object using that. For example if it contains a counter you can do something like.

```
counter = 1 
Browser("B").Page("P").WebButton("B").Click
Browser("B").Page("P").WebEdit("name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l" & counter & "\$ABCName").Set theValue
counter = counter + 1 ' repeat
```

The next best option is if the new `WebEdit` is the added after the previous values, in this case you can use the `index` property

```
counter = 1   
Browser("B").Page("P").WebButton("B").Click
Browser("B").Page("P").WebEdit("name:=\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l.*", "index:=" & counter).Set theValue
counter = counter + 1 ' repeat
```

Worst case (the `name` isn't consistent and nor is its `index`), you can store the names existing `WebEdit`s and see what is new.

```
Set seenEdits = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Function GetNewEdit()
    Set desc = Description.Create()
    desc("name").Value = "\$ABC_1\$ABCList\$l.*"
    Set edits = Browser("B").Page("P").ChildObjects(desc)
    For i = 0 to edits.Count() - 1
        name = edits(i).GetROProperty("name")
        If Not seenEdits.Exists(name) Then
            seenEdits.Add name, True
            Set GetNewEdit edits(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Browser("B").Page("P").WebButton("B").Click
GetNewEdit().Set theValue
```

**Warning:** All code not tested.